# Sencha Touch 2.1 Store Load Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, load, store, sencha-touch-2.1

I am having a problem with loading a store and leaking memory.  I have a store that I need to load every 5 seconds.  I am using DelayedTask to perform the polling.  This app requires the polling and will run for long periods of time.  The store pulls back a fairly large JSON dataset and after a couple hours has hit 500MB.  I perform the polling in a controller.

I have stripped out all logic down to just loading the store.  Regardless if I use DelayedTask or setInterval, the leak is the same.  I've tracked it down to the store.load logic.  Atleast I think I have.  :)

I also removed the callback from store load and performed the task.delay in the load event listener.  The leak still persists.

So, I do not know if I am doing this wrong and introducing closures or is this a bug?

I also used Ext.Ajax to pull the data every 5 seconds.  The memory leak is still there, but it is much smaller.

Any help appreciated!

Model:

```
Ext.define('fimobile.model.myModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'a', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'b', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'c', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'd', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'e', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'f', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'g', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'h', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'i', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'j', type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('fimobile.store.myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'myStoreID',
            model: 'app.model.myModel',
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : url,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
        },  
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('fimobile.controller.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        views: ['myView'],
        models: ['myModel'],
        stores: ['myStore'],
        refs: {  
        },
        control: { 
            'myView': {
                initialize: this.start
            }
        }
    },

    start: function () {        
        task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {      
            this.getData();
        }, this);
        task.delay(5000);
    },

    getData: function() {               
        Ext.getStore('myStore').load({
            scope: this,
            callback : function(records, operation, success) {
                console.log('callback');
                task.delay(5000);
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: maybe the fact you don't have a reference here means you're creating a new instance every time you call getData()... 

perhaps use: 


    myStore = Ext.getStore('myStore');
    myStore.load(...); instead

reusing the reference, rather than creating new anonymous one each time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you post this on the bugs Sencha forum? would be a more sensible place to test a bug?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dawesi.  I did post on their forum.  But was not able to determine the root cause.  I have refactored the code to use Ext.Ajax to pull the data and not use a store for now.  I also have a better understanding of the API and will revisit this issue soon.  If I find the answer, I will post it.